# How to change the Proxy settings in java(Using only IP Address and Port Number)?

Tags: java, proxy, ip, port

I'm trying to change proxy using IP Address and port number only.

This is what my code looks like:

```
try {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "123.125.116.241");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "9999");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Still I won't get any results.

Comment: i can't figure out what is the problem ?

Comment: Please check again. Edited.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally for a https or http connection we implement the code like below:-

```
  URL urlobj = new URL(null , url, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());;
  HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
  //For a http connection
  java.net.URLConnection con = null;
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("http.proxyHost", "9999"));
  con = (proxy != null) ? (HttpsURLConnection) urlobj.openConnection(proxy) : (HttpsURLConnection) urlobj.openConnection();
```

Modify your code for a HTTP connection accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.. but, I want to use only IP address instead of it's domain name...

Comment: yes you can use an IP address in place of host name as well.

Comment: I tried(as you can see my code), but it shows no results. I read somewhere about some permissions. What permissions am I supposed to have to run this code?